# phonegap 2.3 open maps and URLS no longer works on iPhone

Tags: iphone, url, cordova, maps

Just installed phonegap 2.3 and tried to open a maps link that i've created. This was working perfectly fine until the update.

I have tweaked the URL scheme to suit the ones in [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) and i have also tried feeding it a normal url, no matter what i do, i cannot seem to get it to load a link outside the app, whether it be a browser window or the native maps app..

Code:

```
openDeviceMapsApplication: function(address, lat, lon) {
    var query = '?';

    address = address + ", Australia";
    address = encodeURI(address);

    if (address[0] !== '.') {
        query += 'q=' + address + '&';
    } else {
        query += 'q=' + lat + ',' + lon + '&';
    }

    query += 'z=15';


    var url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps';
    var osVersion = "not detected";

    console.log("detect");

    if(/OS [2-4](_\d)(_\d)? like Mac OS X/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { //is it ios 2-4?
        url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps'; osVersion = "ios 2-4";
        console.log("ios2-4");
    } else if(/CPU like Mac OS X/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // ios 1?!?!
        url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps'; osVersion = "ios 1";
        console.log("ios4");
    } else if(/OS [5](_\d)(_\d)? like Mac OS X/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { //ios 5?
        url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps'; osVersion = "ios 5";
                        console.log("ios5");
    } else{//ios 6 or greater
        url = 'http://maps.apple.com/'; osVersion = "ios 6 or greater";
                        console.log("ios6");
    }

    url += query;
    console.log(url);
    window.location.href = url;
    return;

},
```

Does anyone have a workaround?

PS, the os detection works and is ugly.. but it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after much searching and false leads i have found that the URL's are handled differently in this version of Cordova/Phonegap.

So i found the delegate: 
--- edit this delegate method is in CDVViewController.m as part of the Cordova project

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

And added an if-case. The check basically says "is the URL (https or http) and is the URL for (maps.google.com/maps or maps.apple.com - for ios 5 and 6 respectively)

```
if (([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"itms-apps"]) &&
             (([url.path rangeOfString:@"maps.google.com/maps"].location == NSNotFound) || ([url.path rangeOfString:@"maps.apple.com"].location == NSNotFound))) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
```

This fixed the issue for maps, there may be some other URL based application references that this doesn't solve.